# I can't figure out how to use this MapView Library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, maps, zooming

I've been trying to create an indoor map with a Zoom functionality.I found the library "MapView" (https://github.com/peterLaurence/MapView) which is exactly what I would need to achieve what I want. Sadly all of the documentation is in Kotlin and I have no knowledge of Kotlin.

I tried to make a simple programm to start with. I wanted to simply show the map on the screen but it doesn't get drawn at all. I don't get any errors either so I don't really know what I can do.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private TileStreamProvider tileStreamProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView= findViewById(R.id.view);

        mapView = new MapView(this);

        tileStreamProvider = new TileStreamProvider() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public InputStream getTileStream(int row, int col, int zoomLvl) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;

                AssetManager assetManager = MainActivity.this.getAssets();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    try {
                        assetManager.open("tiles/esp/" + zoomLvl + '/' + row + '/' + col + ".jpg");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return inputStream;
            }
        };

        MapViewConfiguration config = new MapViewConfiguration(1, 8192, 8192, 256, tileStreamProvider);
        mapView.configure(config);


    }
}

Any help would be appreciated !
```

EDIT

I tried to do it another way, this time in a fragment and not directly on the main Activity by using the demo that is provided as example. But again since I don't really understand kotlin I may or may not have written soöe stuff the wrong way because I still end up with a white screen in the end.

Here is my code now

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewGroup parentView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        parentView = container;
        MapView mapView = makeMapView(getContext());
        mapView.setId(R.id.mapview_id);
        mapView.setSaveEnabled(true);

        parentView.addView(mapView, 0);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, parentView, false);
        return v;
    }

    private MapView makeMapView(Context context) {
        TileStreamProvider tileStreamProvider = (row, col, zoomLvl) -> {
            try {
                context.getAssets().open("tiles/esp/" + zoomLvl + '/' + row + '/' + col + ".jpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        };
        int tileSize = 256;
        MapViewConfiguration configuration = new MapViewConfiguration(5, 8192, 8192, tileSize, tileStreamProvider).setMaxScale(2f);

        MapView mapView = new MapView(context);
        mapView.configure(configuration);
        return mapView;
    }


}
```

SECOND EDIT

The code for my fragment looks like this now

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);

        MapView mapView = makeMapView(getContext());
        mapView.setId(R.id.mapview_id);
        mapView.setSaveEnabled(true);

        v.addView(mapView);
        return v;
    }

    private MapView makeMapView(Context context) {
        TileStreamProvider tileStreamProvider = (row, col, zoomLvl) -> {
            try {
                context.getAssets().open("tiles/esp/" + zoomLvl + '/' + row + '/' + col + ".jpg");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        };
        int tileSize = 256;
        MapViewConfiguration configuration = new MapViewConfiguration(5, 8192, 8192, tileSize, tileStreamProvider).setMaxScale(2f);

        MapView mapView = new MapView(context);
        mapView.configure(configuration);
        return mapView;
    }


}

but it still doesn't work
```

Comment: Take a look at the library demos, it shows how to attach the view into your fragment (I assume that it could be done in an Activity too)

Comment: I actually did and tried to orient myself using the demos. The problem is that those demos are written in Kotlin, so when I do read the code, there is some stuff that I don't really understand

Comment: Ok, so, as per any regular view, you have to add it to your view group. Let's say that you have a LinearLayout in your activity, once you finish with mapView configuration, you have to add it to your linear layout like: mLinearLayout.addView(mapView)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your instance of MapView into one of your view groups.

Assuming you have a linear layout with the id `R.id.main` in your activity:

```java
LinearLayout mLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
MapView mapView = new MapView(context);
mLayout.addView(mapView);
```

Comment: I think I already do that. In my main Activity I have this code :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
    }
}
which then calls for the fragment and I add the Mapview in my container there.

Or am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: You are adding mapView before inflating. the kotlin also block means: After creating this object, do this with it.
Inflate and then add the view

Comment: I changed to onCreateView to this: 
 {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);

        MapView mapView = makeMapView(getContext());
        mapView.setId(R.id.mapview_id);
        mapView.setSaveEnabled(true);

        container.addView(mapView, 0);
        return v;
    }

the result stays the same though, I get a blank Fragment

Comment: you don't have to add it to `container` but to your view `v.addView`

Comment: but v is a simple View, AddView is not a method I can use on it

Comment: yes, that's why in the demo it has been casted to a `ViewGroup`

Comment: this way then? 
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);

        MapView mapView = makeMapView(getContext());
        mapView.setId(R.id.mapview_id);
        mapView.setSaveEnabled(true);

        v.addView(mapView);
        return v;
    }

it still returns a blank fragment

Comment: your `tileStreamProvider` always returns `null`